# Visualforce PDF with dynamic header footer. but Cover Page should not have header footer

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

I need help in making cover page of PDF different without any header/footer. Rest I was able to complete but how can I remove header/footer from first page that can be used as cover page.

```
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
              @page {
                        @top-center {
                              content: element(header);
                        }
                        @bottom-left {
                            content: element(footer);
                        }
                   }
                   div.header {
                       padding: 10px;
                       position: running(header);
                   }
                   div.footer {
                       display: block;
                       padding: 5px;
                       position: running(footer);
                   }
                   .pagenumber:before {
                        content: counter(page);
                    }
                    .pagecount:before {
                        content: counter(pages);
                    }

         </style>
```

Above code was used for header and footer and its working fine. Need help to change css to set cover page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce PDF generation supports the [:first page pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first).

Here is an example (tested using API 34) where the page number is not displayed on the first page:

```
@page {
    @bottom-right {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 80%;
    }
}
@page :first {
    @bottom-right {
        /* Nothing */
    }
}
```

So I assume (but have not tested) that this would work in your case:

```
@page {
    @top-center {
        content: element(header);
    }
    @bottom-left {
        content: element(footer);
    }
}
@page :first {
    @top-center {
    }
    @bottom-left {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Keith for quick reply. It helped me to resolve it. Below is the complete syntax that was used to hide other elements on cover page:
Thanks Keith for your reply. I got it resolved but somehow it is working in Version 26.0. Its not working with latest versions.

```
@page:first { 
  @top { content: normal }
  @bottom-right { content: normal }
  @top-center {content: normal;}
  @bottom-left {content: normal;}
}
```

Comment: [renderas PDF page level styles not working with v30.0 api](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50627/renderas-pdf-page-level-styles-not-working-with-v30-0-api) may help.